# Typescript dynamically infer type from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a JS Object with React components, indexed by ID.

```js
const MODAL_ENTITIES = {
  changeEmail: ChangeEmailModal,
  changeUsername: ChangeUsernameModal,
};
```

I would like to have a `ModalEntity` type which results in this:

```js
type ModalEntity = {
  id: 'changeEmail',
  props: React.ComponentProps<typeof ChangeEmailModal>
} | {
  id: 'changeUsername',
  props: React.ComponentProps<typeof ChangeUsernameModal>
};
```

My problem is, I want the type to be **dynamically generated** from the `MODAL_ENTITIES` object, since I want the process of adding a modal to be as effortlessly as possible.

Is there a way to define this type dynamically? I could do this but I want to avoid generics, I would like `T` to be inferred:

```js
export type ModalEntity<T extends keyof typeof MODAL_ENTITIES> = {
  id: T;
  props: React.ComponentProps<typeof MODAL_ENTITIES[T]>;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a mockup. The idea is to get generic `T` out of your `ModalEntity` type so that it can be used easily when you add a new modal.

Placeholders for your modals, assuming that each modal has different props:

```js
import React from 'react';

const ChangeEmailModal: React.FC<{ id: string; name: string; email: string }> = ({ id, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <div id={id}>
      {props.name} {props.email}
    </div>
  );
};

const ChangeUsernameModal: React.FC<{ id: string; otherName: string; username: string }> = ({ id, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <div id={id}>
      {props.otherName} {props.username}
    </div>
  );
};

const MODAL_ENTITIES = {
  changeEmail: ChangeEmailModal,
  changeUsername: ChangeUsernameModal
};
```

Then we get the keys from your `MODAL_ENTITIES` in a dynamic way:

```js
export type ModalEntities = typeof MODAL_ENTITIES;

// this gets all the keys in type ModalEntities
type StringKeys<T> = {
  [k in keyof T]: k;
}[keyof T];

type ModalEntitiesKeys = StringKeys<ModalEntities>;
```

Finally:

```js
export type ModalEntity = {
  [K in ModalEntitiesKeys]: {
    id: K;
    props: React.ComponentProps<typeof MODAL_ENTITIES[K]>;
  };
}[ModalEntitiesKeys];
```

The `ModalEntity` type will look like this and it's no longer generic. the type of `props` fields will be inferred dynamically as you requested regardless of different modal props.

```
type ModalEntity = {
    id: "changeEmail";
    props: {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        email: string;
    } & {
        children?: React.ReactNode;
    };
} | {
    id: "changeUsername";
    props: {
        id: string;
        otherName: string;
        username: string;
    } & {
        children?: React.ReactNode;
    };
}
```

You can elaborate more on this idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I forgot to mention this, but not all modals have the same props. In your solution, an instance with id `changeEmail` would still accept the props of `ChangeUsernameModal`.

Comment: Hi @Robrecht, I simplified and updated my answer to be correct, taking into account the information you gave me. I feel like this is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Thanks!